# Javers: Diff DB entities with data from external source without ids

Tags: javers

I'm getting data from an external source with no ids and then I store it in my DB. I'm using Spring with JPA (Hibernate). The ids are autogenerated on the first commit.

The changes in the external data is to be updated every night.

The first commit is trivial. I just create new entities for each new data object and save.

But further on I need to track the changes and just update the existing DB entities that have changed (and add and remove).

It doesn't matter which existing entity is to be updated.

How would I need to approach this using Javers? Is there an example?

Currently I'm thinking about something like:

1. Get existing entities from the DB.
2. Create new entities from the external data.
3. ?

The new entities have no id. I would like to use Javers get the diff without needing any id. Diff the collections only based on the values.

Following a sample entity. None of the values apart the id is unique. Only the comparison of all other values can be used to check the identity to an existing entity.

```
@Entity
@Data
public class TiwHier {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @NotNull
    private Long id;

    @NotBlank
    private String prodId;

    private String pnGuid;
    private String parentPnGuid;

    private String typ;
    private String name;
    private String text;
    private String klasse;
}
```

Comment: This case is not clear for me. If you are synchronizing two databases you need an Id. Otherwiese, each update in the source db will result with an insert in the target

Comment: The source data comes from a database, but from a provided and not modifyable stored procedure where the ids are left out. So, there's an identity and there's an update history in the source, but I have no way to find out, which item has changed in what way. Your comment makes sense: I could / maybe should only delete and add items in the target DB table, so that the target and source tables fit as a whole. There would be no "updates", just "deletes" and "inserts" in the target. The proper "history path" can't be recovered from the source anyway.